# Python, scrapyd installation permision denied, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, scrapyd

I'm a little bit new to python, **scrapy**, and **scrapyd**. I want to install **scrapy** and **scrapyd**.

I installed pip using: `sudo apt-get install pip`

then tried to install **scrapyd**: `pip install scrapyd`

I'm always getting permission denied error and here is the last lines of log:

---

#### LOG:

```
running build_scripts

creating build/scripts-2.7

copying and adjusting bin/scrapyd -> build/scripts-2.7

copying and adjusting bin/scrapyd-deploy -> build/scripts-2.7

changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/scrapyd from 664 to 775

changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/scrapyd-deploy from 664 to 775

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyd': Permission denied
-----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_kamal...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_kamal/scrapyd/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RZBPsI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_kamal/scrapyd
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_kamal/scrapyd/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RZBPsI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_kamal/scrapyd
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Sudo when installing stuff.
So just run the installation again with sudo and it will work.

So it will become:

```
 sudo pip install scrapyd
```

Comment: ya that helped , but the actual issue is that I didn't install python headers "python-dev" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to install a package system-wide, use sudo pip.

```
sudo pip install scrapyd
```

Otherwise, install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), then just pip. This is the better way to do things, because virtualenv lets many different requirement versions coexist in one computer.

```
[sudo] pip install virtualenv # do the sudoing once and for all
virtualenv venv # you can change the destination folder 'venv' to another
source venv/bin/activate
pip install scrapyd
```